# Django-Rest-Framework Relationships & Hyperlinked API issues

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having a go at the django-rest-framework. It was all going fine until I got to the Relationships & Hyperlinked API part of the tutorial. The error I am getting now after messing with it for a bit is:

`ImproperlyConfigured at /api/users/ "^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)$" is not a valid regular expression: redefinition of group name u'format' as group2; was group 1`

I tried doing some research into this but can't seem to find anything and more I mess with it the more that goes wrong

Heres my code:

modules.py

```
class Home(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #address ect
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, view_name='home-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'home')


class HomeSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='home-highlight', read_only=True, format='html')

    class Meta:
        model = Home
        fields = ('url', 'owner', 'postcode')
```

api.py

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'homes': reverse('home-list', request=request, format=format)
    })


class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


class HomeList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Home.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HomeSerializer


class HomeDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Home.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HomeSerializer


class HomeHighlight(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Home.objects.all()
    renderer_classes = (renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = self.get_object()
        return Response(snippet.highlighted)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    url(r'^$', api.api_root),

    url(r'^users/$',
        api.UserList.as_view(),
        name='user-list'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
        api.UserDetail.as_view(),
        name='user-detail'),
    url(r'^home/$',
        api.HomeList.as_view(),
        name='home-list'),
    url(r'^home/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
        api.HomeDetail.as_view(),
        name='home-detail'),
    url(r'^home/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/highlight/$',
        api.HomeHighlight.as_view(),
        name='home-highlight')
])

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                               namespace='rest_framework')),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are calling `format_suffix_patterns` twice, so Django has no idea how to parse the URL because there are two `format` groups.

You shouldn't need the first call, as the second call takes care of it for you (and allows for `TokenAuthentication` to still have the suffixes).

Comment: I was getting the same error because the `DefaultRouter` calls `format_suffix_patterns` in its implementation.

Comment: @Seth which can be resolved by adding `router.include_format_suffixes = False`, after `router = routers.DefaultRouter()`.

Comment: I had urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns) which caused this in urls.py

Answer (score -1):

Atleast change router.DefaultRouter() to router.SimpleRouter() in urls.py file